# How to handle unmatched/unwanted or valid request on Java HTTP Server?

Tags: java, httpserver, json-rpc

I have a Java HTTPServer application listening JSON-RPC format POST requests on localhost:9090 as follows;

```
 HttpServer server = HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(9090), 0);
            System.out.println("> Server started at port number: "+ port);          
            server.createContext("/serverStatus", new RootHandler());
            server.createContext("/newTransaction", new EchoTransactionHandler());
            server.createContext("/", new EchoPostHandler());               
            server.setExecutor(null);
            server.start();
```

I am sending all requests via POST and JSON-RPC format.The EchoPostHandler class meets all post requests made. EchoPosthandler decides which function will work by looking at the request body.

> server.createContext("/", new EchoPostHandler());

All of the post request's url is localhost:9090/.

There are only 2 GET requests. One of these shows the server status. and its url is `localhost:9090/serverStatus`

My problem is; When the user sends an unwanted request, give it an appropriate answer. for example, it can call `localhost:9090/status` instead of calling `localhost:9090/serverStatus` to learn the server status.

I would like to return a proper answer in this case.

How can I handle this task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The URL of all unwanted or non-context-defined requests acts as a base URL.
Therefore, I have added a number of controls in EchoPostHandler to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need a matching URL for every `/<something>` you want to handle. In that regard, `/status` and `/serverstatus`  are quite distinct.

One solution might be to define both URLs and add the same handler to both:

```
HttpHandler hndSystemStatus = new RootHandler();
HttpServer server = HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(9090), 0);
            System.out.println("> Server started at port number: "+ port);          
            server.createContext("/serverStatus", hndSystemStatus );
            server.createContext("/status", hndSystemStatus );
            server.createContext("/newTransaction", new EchoTransactionHandler());
            server.createContext("/", new EchoPostHandler());               
            server.setExecutor(null);
            server.start();
```

Comment: I can't explain the unwanted request part.
the client can send it to "localhost: 9090/serverStatuss"with double "s" instead of "localhost:9090/serverStatus.